# Location of CFBundleDisplayName in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

I'm trying to find out where the `CFBundleDisplayName` is located so I can change the title of my Application in xCode when installed on a device.

It's my understanding the `CFBundleDisplayName` holds the string value for the Title that is displayed underneath the icon on the iPhone screen.

I thought it would be in the `info.plist`, but I cannot see it.
In fact, it's about the only `bundle` not there.

I'm using xCode Version 6.3.1.

How/where can I change this value in xCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your target in Xcode. Then select the Info tab. Under the "Custom iOS Target Properties" section you will see "Bundle Display Name".

Comment: I got told on the Apple Devs forum that that's different to the Bundle Display name? :(

Comment: Also, is it ok to erase `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` and type the new title... It won't affect anything else anywhere in the project?

Comment: I simply entered the desired value in the "Bundle Display Name" field on the "Info" tab.

Comment: Bundle Display Name isn't there :/ All I have is: `Bundle Name`, `Bundle Identifier`, `Bundle Version`, `Bundle creator OS Type code` and `Bundle OS Type code`...

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Add it if it's missing. Hover your mouse over an existing key and click the little + icon. In the new row that appears, select "Bundle Display Name".

Comment: Oh. It does pop up as an option :D Hopefully this works. Thanks for taking the time to post, it's much appreciated :)